# Как преобразовать str(n) в int

Tags: python

Вот код:

```
eq = int(input())
```

допустим вводим 6 ** n

И соответственно выдает ошибку:

```
equation = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'n ** 6'
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: А что вы хотите получить в eq ?

Comment: В eq,хочу получить какое-либо выражение с n: 6^n или например 5 - 1^n

Comment: переменная может содержать "выражение" в виде строки или в виде функции. Вы игпут преобразуете в инт, соответственно, там может быть только число

Comment: Т.е я никак не могу преобразовать n в int,что бы строка eq =int(input()),не выдавала ошибку?

Comment: N это буква, как её в инт перевести?

Comment: Да,ибо как бы я не пытался,выдает ошибку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вот так:

```
n = 7
res = eval(input())

# -> 2 ** n
# <- 128
```

Но, это абсолютно небезопасно

Comment: Вы не сказали, что eval это любая команда питону

Comment: А вы почитайте про нее, заодно и про другие функции почитайте, что же тут, документацию всю пересказывать? :) https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: Ооо,спасибо большое!

Comment: Не за что :). Напомню еще раз, что нельзя передавать в `eval` данные, которые могут быть потенциально опасные. Если ответ действительно помог, то стоит отметить его галочкой

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
n=input()
n=int(n)
print('6^'+str(n))
print(6**n)
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает(

Comment: @ВладимирЖмых А так???

Comment: ДА!СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ

Comment: Не за что......

Comment: Только,надо что бы можно было ввести любое выражение,6^n это я для примера использовал

Comment: Ну так у меня ```input()```

Comment: Боюсь вы не совсем меня поняли,точнее я не совсем верно объяснил,надо что бы питон выводил выражение через инпут с n т.е допусти я ввожу 6**n,после чего он его выводит в таком же виде и подставляет уже следующей строкой туда число вместо n,надеюсь так понятней)